# "I have chosen," "I choose," or "I am choosing"?

Tags: grammar, tenses

In a week time I'm taking an exam. I want to know whether I can say 'I have chosen' or not. It is present perfect too.

The task is:

> You would like to go on a party. Look at the picture and decide which outfit would suit you best. Justify your opinion.

The problem is that English is not my native language, and my teacher said that "I have chosen is wrong," but (as far as I know) it also indicates finished action: "I have just done my homework, I have already seen the film." Why is it wrong then if it is at all? Other options have been suggested, e.g. *I am choosing*, *I chose*, or *I choose*.

Anyway, I'm not convinced, as they all refer to different tenses. Why would *I've chosen* be wrong?

Comment: Please tell us the full sentence where you used "I have chosen".

Answer (score 6):

I think you have to take your lead from the question. You have to *decide which outfit **would** suit you best*.

Comment: A definite up-vote for the choice of answer. 

I wonder what could be wrong with using "I have/had chosen" otherwise. Isn't 'would' a form of past tense? I always had this doubt about 'would'. 

I just thought of asking it here because it is relevant, didn't intend to hijack.

Comment: @Fr0zenFyr: 'Would' is a modal verb which, depending  on context, can express habit, volition, prediction or unreal meaning. If the question asked about the picture is a hypothetical one, so you can't use use 'have chosen' or 'had chosen', because that would indicate something you had done which in fact you hadn't. 'Would' expresses your choice if you were in a postion to make it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Barrie. I now have a clearer picture but I guess I need to keep noticing the correct usage a bit more to use it properly myself. Cheers!!

Comment: You nailed it :)

Answer (score 4):

You could go with any of the three, as well as others. Moreover, despite what your teacher says, it is grammatical English to use any of the following:

> I choose X.
>   I chose X.
>   I have chosen X.
>   I am choosing X.
>   I will choose X.

These all suggest that you are relating to another party a choice that you have made. A native English speaker would understand any of them to mean that you are announcing your decision.

Comment: They're all grammatical, but, as Barrie says, they don't all match the question. "I would choose" matches the question.

Comment: @ColinFine: The question is very vague and poorly expressed. Barrie is responding to what he imagines the situation to be — one possibility among many — and that is an easy question to answer. But remember, the decision has already been made and the opinion is being justified at that point, so the decision may be expressed as a past event, a present event, or anything of the other examples above. It does not have to be expressed as a conditional.

Comment: I read the second paragraph of the question as quoting the relevant section from the exam verbatim, and I believe Barrie did so as well.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing grammatically wrong with “I have chosen ...”, as @Robusto says, but considering the question, I’d say that the best response is “I would choose ...”

Answer (score 0):

*I have chosen* is correct.

> - **I have chosen** not to go to the party.
> - I am very thankful because **you have chosen** me to become one of your English teachers.

Both are OK to use.